# Google Colab / Google Drive and h5py file storage

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, h5py

I'am trying to train a UNet neural network with data stored on my google drive with Google Colab.

I created a core library, a dataset etc... But it was slow to access data.

In order to prevent it, I've build a ".hdf5" file with h5py library.

```
XDataPath="/content/drive/My Drive/Dataset/data/X"
YDataPath="/content/drive/My Drive/Dataset/data/Y"
h5Path="/content/drive/My Drive/Dataset/data/dataset.hdf5"
nbX=len(os.listdir(XDataPath))
nbY=len(os.listdir(YDataPath))

# CleanData
dst=[os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in os.listdir(YDataPath)]
src=[os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in os.listdir(XDataPath)]
for f in src:
  if f not in dst:
    fpth=os.path.join(XDataPath,f+'.jpg')
    os.remove(fpth)
    print(fpth)
for f in dst:
  if f not in src:
    fpth=os.path.join(YDataPath,f+'.png')
    os.remove(fpth)
    print(fpth)

with h5py.File(h5Path,'a') as hfile:
  if not "X" in hfile:
    hfile.create_dataset("X",(nbX,512,512,3))
  if not "Y" in hfile:
    hfile.create_dataset("Y",(nbY,512,512))

for i,Path in tqdm.tqdm_notebook(enumerate(os.listdir(XDataPath)),total=nbX):
    ImPath=os.path.join(XDataPath,Path)
    with h5py.File(h5Path,'a') as hfile:
        with Image.open(ImPath) as f:
            X=np.array(f)
            hfile["X"][i]=X
```

The file is correctly created :

[image]

What is surprising for me is that i don't see this file on my google drive (only a 0ko file with the same name).
More, i don't have enough storage in order to store it

[image]

Why this file is not created on the drive ?
Where is it stored ?

Another problem is that when i restart the environment, the hdf5 file is now 0ko, like on my google drive.. And empty of course !

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The file is created and stored in Google Cloud(Colab instance). The file is too big, so it cannot be synced back to Google Drive.

So, I suggest you use a GCS bucket to store it instead of GDrive.